# Can I make more money freelancing in Android, or Web development?

Tags: web-development, freelancing, android, business

**Is freelancing in Android development or Web development the better choice to achieve a ~300$ income\month?** It is too hard for me to do both.

I'm currently studying CS in college and this is my second year. Financially, I'm 100% depending on my parents and this is really uncomfortable for me. My goal is to make at least 300$ a month with freelancing in programming. The problem is, I don't know where to start. I have a solid background in Java and have a basic knowledge of C, PHP, Javascript, Ruby, Prolog, CSS, HTML. I think my options are to go do Web development or Android development. I've already tried both of them (made a basic app for Android and a simple blog). It's kinda hard for me to do the both at the same time. Ultimately my question is, which one should I continue to work with to achieve the desired income\month? I really love doing both of them so I'm asking you guys to give me some helpful advice. Thank you for your time.

EDIT: Sorry for being off topic but I didn't knew where to ask. There are many experts on this site so it seemed logical to ask it here. Feel free to delete this post and sorry for braking the rules.

Comment: This is off-topic here: we can't tell you what you should do with your career or how you can make $300/month.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My suggestion, as always, is oDesk.com. There you can find a lot of jobs, they pay fast, they are reliable and you can manage your time as you want. The only thing you need is: programming skills and English.

300 per month doing Android Development? You must be kidding. I earn that in two days... and trust me, I am really newbie to Android.